# ios objective C ,bool toggle warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, boolean

bool toggle gives warning,

i have seen that to [toggle a Bool](http://matthewfecher.com/app-developement/practical-objective-c-how-to-toggle-a-boolean/) , I can use

```
self.calendarIsShowing = !self.calendarIsShowing;
```

but I get this warning,

```
Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'BOOL *' (aka 'signed char *)from 'int'
```

it still works, I just want to fix the warning,
thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I bet your property is...

```
@property BOOL * calendarIsShowing;
```

but it should be

```
@property BOOL calendarIsShowing;
```